# how to stop intellij incorrectly treating a normal directory as a package

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

See in image I don;t want the webapp directory treated as package. And I don;t want to exclude from indexing - the indexing is great.

Comment: Don't configure the directory (and any of its parents) as **Sources** in the project structure, module settings.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You should put that as an answer so he can mark it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't configure the directory (and any of its parents) as **Sources** in the `Project Structure`, module settings.

IntelliJ IDEA interprets a directory as a package only for the the directories under the source roots.